# Build and Deploy Flutter iOS App to TestFlight: Fastlane & GitHub Actions

Tags: flutter, dart, github, github-actions, fastlane

I'm attempting to build and deploy an iOS app to TestFlight using Fastlane and GitHub Actions.

Here's the issue I'm encountering:

**Local Success**: When running Fastlane commands directly in my Terminal, the build and deployment to TestFlight succeed.

**GitHub Actions Issue**: In my GitHub Actions workflow, the process proceeds smoothly until the gym step. At this point, I encounter errors (please see the error output below).

```
Resolved source packages
[14:07:49]: ▸ swift-collections - https://github.com/apple/swift-collections @ 1.0.6
[14:07:49]: ▸ swift-log - https://github.com/apple/swift-log.git @ 1.5.4
[14:07:49]: ▸ aws-sdk-swift - https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-swift.git @ 0.31.0
[14:07:49]: ▸ Starscream - https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream @ 4.0.4
[14:07:49]: ▸ AmplifyUtilsNotifications - https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift-utils-notifications.git @ 1.1.1
[14:07:49]: ▸ SQLite.swift - https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift.git @ 0.13.2
[14:07:49]: ▸ XMLCoder - https://github.com/MaxDesiatov/XMLCoder.git @ 0.17.0
[14:07:49]: ▸ AmplifyUILiveness - https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ui-swift-liveness @ 1.2.2
[14:07:49]: ▸ Amplify - https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-swift @ 2.25.5
[14:07:49]: ▸ AppSyncRealTimeClient - https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-appsync-realtime-client-ios.git @ 3.1.2
[14:07:49]: ▸ smithy-swift - https://github.com/smithy-lang/smithy-swift @ 0.35.0
[14:07:49]: ▸ aws-crt-swift - https://github.com/awslabs/aws-crt-swift @ 0.17.0
[14:07:57]: ▸ 2024-02-27 14:07:57.243 xcodebuild[14923:43414] [MT] IDEFileReferenceDebug: [Load] <IDESwiftPackageCore.IDESwiftPackageSpecialFolderFileReference, 0x600005cd1b00: name:Docs.docc path:group:Docs.docc> Failed to load container at path: /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bvhnnwsbqawhdsazvgxqinopppxn/SourcePackages/checkouts/swift-log/Sources/Logging/Docs.docc, Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6 "Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot open "Docs.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder".}
[14:07:57]: ▸ 2024-02-27 14:07:57.361 xcodebuild[14923:43414] [MT] IDEFileReferenceDebug: [Load] <IDESwiftPackageCore.IDESwiftPackageSpecialFolderFileReference, 0x600005c3bf00: name:OrderedCollections.docc path:group:OrderedCollections.docc> Failed to load container at path: /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bvhnnwsbqawhdsazvgxqinopppxn/SourcePackages/checkouts/swift-collections/Sources/OrderedCollections/OrderedCollections.docc, Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6 "Cannot open "OrderedCollections.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot open "OrderedCollections.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder".}
[14:07:57]: ▸ 2024-02-27 14:07:57.366 xcodebuild[14923:43414] [MT] IDEFileReferenceDebug: [Load] <IDESwiftPackageCore.IDESwiftPackageSpecialFolderFileReference, 0x600005ce9400: name:DequeModule.docc path:group:DequeModule.docc> Failed to load container at path: /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bvhnnwsbqawhdsazvgxqinopppxn/SourcePackages/checkouts/swift-collections/Sources/DequeModule/DequeModule.docc, Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6 "Cannot open "DequeModule.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot open "DequeModule.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder".}
[14:07:57]: ▸ 2024-02-27 14:07:57.372 xcodebuild[14923:43414] [MT] IDEFileReferenceDebug: [Load] <IDESwiftPackageCore.IDESwiftPackageSpecialFolderFileReference, 0x600005cea100: name:Collections.docc path:group:Collections.docc> Failed to load container at path: /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-bvhnnwsbqawhdsazvgxqinopppxn/SourcePackages/checkouts/swift-collections/Sources/Collections/Collections.docc, Error: Error Domain=com.apple.dt.IDEContainerErrorDomain Code=6 "Cannot open "Collections.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder"." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Cannot open "Collections.docc" as a "Swift Package Folder" because it is already open as a "Folder".}
[14:08:05]: ▸ ::error file=/Users/runner/work/app/app/ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig,line=2,col=1::could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths
[14:08:05]: ▸ /Users/runner/work/app/app/ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig:2:1: error: could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths
[14:08:05]: ▸ /Users/runner/work/app/app/ios/Flutter/Release.xcconfig:2:1: error: could not find included file 'Generated.xcconfig' in search paths
[14:08:05]: ▸ ::warning ::Unable to read contents of XCFileList '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
[14:08:05]: ▸ ::error ::error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-input-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
[14:08:05]: ▸ ::error ::error: Unable to load contents of file list: '/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Release-output-files.xcfilelist' (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
[14:08:05]: ▸ ::warning ::Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
[14:08:05]: ▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
```

**Build environment**

[image]
**Lane Context**
[image]

**fastlane summary**

[image]

And here is my Git Actions For Flutter Ios:

```
name: iOS TestFlight Deployment

on:
  push:
    branches: [feature/ios_fastlane_setup]

jobs:
  build-and-deploy-ios:
    runs-on: macos-latest

    steps:
      - name: Set up git and fetch all history for all branches and tags
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0

      - name: Set up Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: "2.7"
      - name: List files in iOS Runner directory
        run: ls -la ${{ github.workspace }}/ios/Runner
      - name: Bundle install for iOS Gemfile
        timeout-minutes: 5
        run: |
          cd ${{ github.workspace }}/ios
          bundle install --path vendor/bundle
      - name: Set up Flutter SDK
        uses: subosito/flutter-action@v2
        with:
          flutter-version: "3.16.2"
          channel: "stable"
          architecture: x64
          cache: true
      - name: Install Fastlane
        run: |
          flutter clean
          flutter build
        env:
          APP_STORE_CONNECT_TEAM_ID: "${{ secrets.APP_STORE_CONNECT_TEAM_ID }}"
          DEVELOPER_APP_ID: "${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_APP_ID }}"
          DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER: "${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER }}"
          DEVELOPER_PORTAL_TEAM_ID: "${{ secrets.DEVELOPER_PORTAL_TEAM_ID }}"
          FASTLANE_APPLE_ID: "${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_ID }}"
          FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD: "${{ secrets.FASTLANE_APPLE_APPLICATION_SPECIFIC_PASSWORD }}"
          MATCH_PASSWORD: "${{ secrets.MATCH_PASSWORD }}"
          GIT_AUTHORIZATION: "${{ secrets.GIT_AUTHORIZATION }}"
          PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER: "${{ secrets.PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER }}"
          TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: "${{ secrets.TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}"
          TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER: "${{ secrets.TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER }}"
          APPLE_KEY_ID: "${{ secrets.APPLE_KEY_ID }}"
          APPLE_ISSUER_ID: "${{ secrets.APPLE_ISSUER_ID }}"
          APPLE_KEY_CONTENT: "${{ secrets.APPLE_KEY_CONTENT }}"
      - name: Deploy iOS Beta to TestFlight via Fastlane
        uses: maierj/fastlane-action@v3.1.0
        with:
          lane: "closed_beta"
          subdirectory: "ios"
```

And my Fastlane code:

```
default_platform(:ios)
ENV["FASTLANE_XCODEBUILD_SETTINGS_TIMEOUT"] = "120"
DEVELOPER_APP_ID = ENV["DEVELOPER_APP_ID"]
DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER = ENV["DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER"]
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = ENV["PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER"]
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER = ENV["TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER"]
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD = ENV["TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"]
APPLE_ISSUER_ID = ENV["APPLE_ISSUER_ID"]
APPLE_KEY_ID = ENV["APPLE_KEY_ID"]
APPLE_KEY_CONTENT = ENV["APPLE_KEY_CONTENT"]
GIT_AUTHORIZATION = ENV["GIT_AUTHORIZATION"]
FASTLANE_XCODEBUILD_SETTINGS_TIMEOUT=ENV["FASTLANE_XCODEBUILD_SETTINGS_TIMEOUT"] = "120"
# ENV['ITMSTRANSPORTER_FORCE_ITMS_PACKAGE_UPLOAD'] = 'true'
def delete_temp_keychain(name)
  delete_keychain(
    name: name
  ) if File.exist? File.expand_path("~/Library/Keychains/#{name}-db")
end

def create_temp_keychain(name, password)
  create_keychain(
    name: name,
    password: password,
    unlock: false,
    timeout: 0
  )
end

def ensure_temp_keychain(name, password)
  delete_temp_keychain(name)
  create_temp_keychain(name, password)
end
        
platform :ios do
  lane :closed_beta do
    keychain_name = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER
    keychain_password = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD
    ensure_temp_keychain(keychain_name, keychain_password)

    api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
      key_id: APPLE_KEY_ID,
      issuer_id: APPLE_ISSUER_ID,
      key_content: APPLE_KEY_CONTENT,            
      duration: 1200,            
      in_house: false
    )
    
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "Runner.xcodeproj")
    
   

    match(
      type: 'appstore',
      app_identifier: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER}",
      git_basic_authorization: Base64.strict_encode64(GIT_AUTHORIZATION),
      readonly: true,
      keychain_name: keychain_name,
      keychain_password: keychain_password,
      api_key: api_key
    )

    # Build the App
  
      gym(
        configuration: "Release",
        workspace: "Runner.xcworkspace",
        scheme: "Runner",
        export_method: "app-store",
        export_options: {
          provisioningProfiles: { 
              DEVELOPER_APP_ID => PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER
          }
        }
      )
  
      pilot(
        apple_id: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_ID}",
        app_identifier: "#{DEVELOPER_APP_IDENTIFIER}",
        skip_waiting_for_build_processing: true,
        skip_submission: true,
        distribute_external: false,
        notify_external_testers: false,
        ipa: "./ozqr.ipa"
      )

    delete_temp_keychain(keychain_name)
  end
end
```

Comment: Fixed the issue

Comment: Hi, can you give more details on how to fix this issue please? And also is ther any tutorial i can watch to make this ci/cd pipeline?